# Boot Problem : Missing Operating System

Tags: boot, boot-repair

A sudden power cut caused my ubuntu not booting any more with the error '`Missing operating system`'. No GRUB menu appeared at all.

I tried using `boot-repair` to solve this problem, but that didn't help.

`boot info` here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1177698/

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.
- Check your disk and partitions for errors and fix them with GParted.
- Try booting again.

---

[image: Filesystem check]